# What is the origin of the truth table in logic?

Tags: logic, history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-logic, history-of-logic

Specifically for the material implication if possible. Who was the first to use a truth table for this and justify its validity?

Comment: really, all a truth table is, is a definition.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson But it had to originate from somewhere, and have a justification behind it.

Comment: the question of origin can be applied to anything.  definitions don't require justification.  they're axioms.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The question of origin can be applied to anything, I don't see that as a problem. As for justification, there must be a reason for the definition. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson In mathematics, definitions and axioms are not the same. Axioms are the foundation for a theory, while definitions are merelyhandy abbreviations.

Comment: a truth table is a definition and, if you want, a truth table is a collection of axioms.  whatever you want to call it, they are just **given** not derived.

Answer (score 14):

You can see:

- Irving Anellis, [The Genesis of the Truth-Table Device](https://escarpmentpress.org/russelljournal/article/viewFile/2056/2081) (2004)

as well as:

- Irving Anellis, [Peirce's Truth-functional Analysis and the Origin of the Truth Table](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2429) (2012).

Before Bertrand Russell (Harvard logic course: 1914) and Ludwig Wittgenstein (Russell and Wittgenstein's manuscript dated 1912; see also: [Tractatus (1921), **4.31** and **4.442**](https://books.google.it/books?id=p86r0bvRxQAC&pg=PA38) for *material implication*), [Charles Sanders Peirce](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-logic/) and his followers must be credited.

See [Christine Ladd-Franklin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_Ladd-Franklin), “On the Algebra of Logic”, in Charles Sanders Peirce (editor), [Studies in Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=GRlCAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA62) (1883), page 17-on; see pages 61-62.

In Whitehead and Russell's [*Principia* (page 115)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA115), we have a description of the truth-functional semantics of connective : *not, if..., then..., and, or* (but not in tabular form).

The modern tabular form is present in E.Post, [Introduction to a General Theory of Elementary Propositions (1921)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2370324?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), §2 *Truth table development*, with explicit reference to W&R's *Principia* (see footnote 6).

---

The verbal" description of *conditional* is in Frege's [Begriffsschrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift).

But it was already verbally stated in [Ancient Stoic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ancient/#SynSemComPro) with the so-called *philonian conditional*; see [Sextus Empiricus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextus_Empiricus), [Πρὸς μαθηματικούς (*Pros mathematikous*)](https://books.google.it/books?id=tldNUcD9Qn0C&pg=pa112) **Book VIII**, 113:

> Philo, for example, said that the conditional is true when it does not begin with a true proposition and finish with a false one, so that a conditional, according to him, is true in three ways and false in one way. For when it begins with a true one and finishes with a true one, it is true, as in “If it is day, it is light.” And when it begins with a false one and finishes with a false one, it is again true – for example, “If the earth flies, the earth has wings.”